# How to do the following move instruction in NASM?

Tags: assembly, nasm

Suppose that I have a label called

`some_number: resd 1`

which will contain a number from 1 to 10 that will be determined by what the user inputs and a buffer

```
buf:   resb 32
```

now, I want to do the following:

```
mov [buf + 32 - [some_number]], 1
```

i.e., I want to move the number 1 into the what is referenced by the memory address buf + 32 - [some_number] (this is the number that the user inputs). Does this work? If not, how can one do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```
mov ebx, buf+32
sub ebx, dword [some_number]
mov byte [ebx], 1
```